# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " position: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

> rake aborted!
>
> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "                  position: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
>
> (in F:/OrderBooking/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
>   (sass):340
>
> Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

In my local machine there is no error, but while deploying my application, I am getting the above error. But in my `application.css` i have nothing in it.

Comment: please add your `sass` file here

Answer (score 4):

Syntax errors in CSS are ignored in development environment, but in production environment while precompiling assets these errors come. So to make sure your CSS has no syntax errors, every time before uploading to production, run the following command, fine if it runs successfully, if it throws error then fix the syntax error, following is the command

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile
```

In your case, the error says, **In your `application.css.scss`, in line number `340`, there's a syntax error. So you need to fix the syntax error and deploy again to Heroku**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i have no code in `assets/stylesheets/application.css`, but i have another file name `assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`..is this is responsible for the error

Comment: Yes, check line no. 340

Comment: what css files you have?

Comment: i have found the error in another css file....but the error log tells me the incorrect file name...now its working, but i have another question to ask u, that while redirecting to another page i am getting error in production environment only.How do i found errors in heroku?

Comment: Its because the file in which error was present was included in `application.css.scss` by using `require`, there must be `require file_name` or `require tree` present in application.css.scss

Comment: @Зелёный I have encountered this situation several times, though that property won't work but it won't throw error. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Зелёный It might be true (and the CSS error will reach the client's browser, which will choke on it), but not with **Sass**, which is what the question is about. So... you're both sorta right.

Answer (score 0):

I got this one time because I was trying to use `<script src="` on CSS on my index.html file instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href=`