# Assets Precompile When Explicitly Invoked, Breaks During Capistrano Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using Rails 4.2, and Capistrano 3. When I run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, everything works out nice and dandy, however when I use Capistrano to deploy the site, I get this error during the asset:precompile step.

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as xxx@123.45.67.89: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " */": expected "}", was ""
(sass):6831
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1161:in `expected'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1097:in `expected'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1092:in `tok!'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:639:in `block'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:631:in `ruleset'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:656:in `block_child'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:649:in `block_contents'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:117:in `stylesheet'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:403:in `_to_tree'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/xxx/Sites/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

I have noticed that if I remove the line `*= require styles` in my `application.css` file, it successfully deploys, but obviously that is not the solution I am looking for. My assets/stylesheets file-structure is shown below:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " position: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799303/sasssyntaxerror-invalid-css-after-position-expected-expression-e-g-1p)

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command compiles assets locally in your dev environment:

```bash
rake assets:precompile
```

During deployment `capistrano` the following task is being invoked (as you can see on top of your backtrace):

```bash
cap env_name deploy:assets:precompile
```

which on it's part invokes this on remote server:

```bash
rake assets:precompile
```

*Asset precompilation in development environment **ignores** syntax errors*.

Try running this command locally to find and fix those errors:

```bash
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
```